# Select Menu Resets to Previously Selected Option

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a select menu that fires an ajax post then displays a success or failure message on :success.

The HTML for the menu looks like so:

```
<select name="return_action_id" class="form-control">
    <option value="0"> --- Please Select --- </option>
    <option value="1" selected>Refunded</option>
    <option value="2">Credit Issued</option>
    <option value="3">Replacement Sent</option>
</select>
```

The Javascript for the ajax post looks like so:

```
$('select[name="return_action_id"]').change(function(){
    var a=$(this);
    var value = a.val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'index.php?route=sale/returns/action&token=<?= $token; ?>&return_id=<?= $return_id; ?>',
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        data:'return_action_id='+value,
        beforeSend:function(){
            a.blur().button('loading').append($('<i>',{class:'icon-loading'}));
        },
        complete:function(){
            a.button('reset');
        },
        success:function(json){
            if(json['error']){
                alertMessage('danger',json['error']);
            }
            if(json['success']){
                alertMessage('success',json['success']);
                //$('select[name="return_action_id"] option:selected').prop('selected', false);
                //$('select[name="return_action_id"] option[value="'+value+'"]').prop('selected', true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Every time I select an option from the menu, the Ajax fires and creates my message as expected, but the option selected does not receive the selected property and the menu reverts back to the originally selected option.

For instance in the html code above, Refunded is currently selected. If I select Credit Issued in the menu, the Ajax fires and the menu reverts back to having Refunded selected.

You'll see in the javascript success method I have some code commented out where I tried to make it behave.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You reset the `select` menu here `a.button('reset');`?

Comment: Yep that was it, that's what I get for recycling code.  Thanks a bunch.  If you submit this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I submited as an answer :), i'm glad that i helped you :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reset the `select` menu here `a.button('reset')`, remove this line and the current value will remain selected.